# How to use Font Awesome in react native project without using any third party library?

Tags: android, react-native, font-awesome

I want to use Font Awesome icons in my react-native project for android.

I want to do it manually without using any third party library like `react-native-vector-icons` or others.

Comment: Why you don't want to use any third party?

Comment: i want to do it manually so that i can know whats going on under the hood.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

i am answering it for android And ios

download font awesome zip extract the files copy fontawesome-webfont.ttf file

1. make  **/assets/fonts/** directory in your project directory
2. paste  **fontawesome-webfont.ttf** into **/assets/fonts/**
3. rename the file to **fontawesome.ttf**
4. add

   `"rnpm": {
       "assets": [
         "./assets/fonts/"
       ]
     }`
   into your end of **package.json** file like this

[image]

4. run `react-native link` command into terminal in your project directory

see reslut like this

```
rnpm-install info Linking assets to ios project
rnpm-install info Linking assets to android project
rnpm-install info Assets have been successfully linked to your project
```

5. make sure run again `react-native run-android` command after successfully linked

go to [fontawesome cheatsheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/)

copy only the character code of the icon you want to apply to a text view and paste it

```
<Text style={{ fontFamily: 'fontawesome', fontSize: 20 }}>&#xf0a9;</Text>
```

apply style `fontFamily: 'fontawesome'`

similarly you can do it for other vector icon fonts like [ionicons](http://ionicons.com/)

and others without using third party library like `react-native-vector-icons`

Comment: I think font-awesome is overall is a font that looks like icon what library you have suggested uses the fontawesome font not the icons #kalibbala

Comment: I used this approach for Material Icons and worked! To know the postscript name of the font file check this out https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18269#issuecomment-371531245

Comment: i have importetd FontAwesome like You described here but it displays only about the half of all free icons.
is that normal or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: It says unrecognized font-family `fontawesome `

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit old, but still. If you are using Create React Native App, I think this is the easiest way. Download the font and place it into 'projectfolder/assets/fonts/' directory. I renamed it to 'fontawesome.ttf'.

After that you'll need to install expo package if you don't already have it.

```
npm install --save expo
```

And add following lines to your index (App.js) file.

Firstly:

```
import { Font } from 'expo';
```

Then load the font. This code goes inside your App component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  Font.loadAsync({
    'Font Awesome': require('./assets/fonts/fontawesome.ttf')
  });
}
```

To make sure you did everything alright:

```
<Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Font Awesome', fontSize: 20 }}>&#xf164;</Text>
```

[Those are original instructions.](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts.html)

I just wanted to make it visible without visiting the link.

Comment: The question is asking how to add icons(fontAwesome), not adding FONTS.

Comment: Package you recommended in your answer does the same thing under the hood **uses Font Awesome icons which is a font and nothing else**. So if you want to add Font Awesome Icons to your site/app you add it as a font.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension of the answer by Hastig (Accepted answer for this post), I hope he doesn't mind:

If you are looking for the character code, just go to the glyphs info page e.g. https://fontawesome.com/v5/icons/search?f=classic&s=solid

Take the unicode and append it to "&#x"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -5):

1. Install font-awesome library.

> npm i --save react-native-fontawesome

2. Import font-awesome in your file, Add:

> import FontAwesome, { Icons } from 'react-native-fontawesome';

3. Call icons where you want in your file.

> {Icons.chevronLeft}

**Note:** 
After Step 1 make sure **"react-native-fontawesome": "Version here"** shows under dependencies in your package.json file(root application folder).

**For More:**
https://github.com/entria/react-native-fontawesome

Comment: Perhaps you have not gone through the question properly, the question about using fontawesome icons in react-native project without using any third party library. What you have suggested is  a third party library react-native-fontawesome. First go through the question before answering