# How to add font Awesome in a react-native project for android?

Tags: android, react-native, font-awesome

I'm able to add normal fonts, but not [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/cheatsheet/), i'm using v4.7.0 of FontAwesome.

I've checked older answers on SO, but I only found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45906391/how-to-use-font-awesome-icon-in-react-native-project-for-android) to be relevant, but I think the answer is outdated, because you cant link fonts with the first letter of the file name being lowercase, it has to be uppercase, like 'Font Awesome.ttf' for example(which is what I have right now). This naming strategy worked for adding another regular font called 'Titillium Web'.

**My index.js**

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.fontawesome}>&#xf0c9;</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  fontawesome:{
    fontFamily: 'Font Awesome',
    color: '#000',
    fontSize: 20 
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myappname', () => App);
```

**In my package.json**

```
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/assets/fonts/TitilliumWeb",
      "./src/assets/fonts/FontAwesome"
    ]
  },
```

**Executed** `react-native link` in project dir, the fonts were copied correctly.

**Executed** `react-native run-android` in project dir.

**My Environment**

- Device: real device, android kitkat v4.4.2
- react-native:  v0.55.2
- react: v16.3.1
- yarn: v1.5.1
- node:  v9.5.0

Comment: why you add `space` at `fontFamily`? maybe that's your problem, you should use `fontFamily: 'FontAwesome',`

Comment: Tried all possible combinations you could think of. I eventually gave up and started a new project, and used react-native-vector-icons lib in it.

Comment: fontawesome you used is for styling a text or adding an icon?

Comment: I downloaded it from this link https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0.zip and opened the font folder and copied the .ttf file to my project

Comment: why dont you use [vector icon](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) for an icon?

Comment: Tried many times with vector icons and failed to render them, only png icons worked tho. font icons aren't so bad.

Comment: if you want to create a custom icon, and you have a `SVG` file, you can follow [this tutorial](https://www.reactnative.guide/12-svg-icons-using-react-native-vector-icons/12.1-creating-custom-iconset.html)