# Troubles when using FontAwesome's unicodes in JSX

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using FontAwesome with React Native (CRNA) with expo. I loaded my font with the official [tutorial](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts) from expo. I don't understand how to use the unicode in the JSX. For example, I followed this [helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46642951/10160210) from an another thread :

- It's work for the unicode : `&#xf164;`
- I tried to use this unicode after `&#xf1ce;` after. It doesn't work.

Do you have a solution ? This is my code :

```
<View>
     <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Font Awesome', fontSize: 20 }}>
         &#xf1ce;
     </Text>
</View>
```

I think, I cleary don't understand maybe an unicode.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's working with the other unicode, probably the version of Font Awesome that you are using doesn't have that unicode

Comment: Have you tried `fontFamily: 'FontAwesome'`?

Comment: @alexhenkel Thanks you for your answer. I have the good version of Font Awesome. I downloaded the latest version of FA from the official website, in v5.
@JoseVf Thanks you for your answer. I declared the Font Family as `'Font Awesome'`. It's not that.